# Why is POST method not working with Codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, host, codeigniter-4

I have a basic html form. Instead using with localhost it works well but as for a real host only incomeing POSTs not working. I have been still working on it bu could not any solition. Here is my information.

In real host my folder codeigniter 4 folder design
|-codeigniter
|-app
|-system
|-writable
|-.env
|-assets
|-css
|-cs
|-index.php
|-.htaccess

In index.php
`$pathsPath = realpath(FCPATH . './codeigniter/app/Config/Paths.php');`

In View folder here is my html codes
and base_url is `` public $baseURL = 'http://`www.catidekorasyon.com/panel/'; ``

```
<form  action="<?php echo base_url('ayarlar/guncelle'); ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Web Sitesi İsmi</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Web Sitesi İsmi" name="siteismi"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group mb-0">
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light mr-1">
         Güncelle
      </button>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

and In controller/ayarlar.php

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;



class Ayarlar extends BaseController
{


    public $viewFolder="";

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->viewFolder = "ayarlar_v";
            $this->ayarlarModel = model('App\Models\AyarlarModel', false);
        
            $this->session=session();

            // Your own constructor code
    }


    public function guncelle(){

      $siteismi=$this->request->getPost("siteismi");

      print_r($siteismi);

    }



}
```

And the end of day results is empty
`Array()`

May be problem's sourche is real host could not solve yet.
Are there anybody who knows ehich's promles's source is codeigniter 4 or host?

Comment: Check what url you get on host from `<?php echo base_url('ayarlar/guncelle'); ?>` code.

Comment: Also check `getPost()` method without parameters and `$_POST` array.

Comment: not working also